# How to make simple alarms on Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple alarm using Python but whatever I try it doesn't seem to work. I've just recently made a timer but an alarm would be a little more useful.
I'm also pretty new to Python so I'm not really aware of all the rules and syntax.

```
import datetime
import os
stop = False
while stop == False:
    rn = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    print(rn)
    if rn == "18:00:00.000000":
        stop = True
        os.system("start BTS_House_Of_Cards.mp3")
```

[When I run the file, it prints the time but goes completely past the time I want the alarm to go off at.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Aodv.png)

Comment: The alarm only fires if `datetime.now()` is *exactly* `"18:00:00.000000"`.  What happens if you call `datetime.now()` at 17:59:59.999999 and then call it at 18:00:00.000001?

Comment: You would have to get very lucky to hit 18:00:00.000000 exactly.

Comment: So would I have to use a range with '<' or '>'?

Comment: datetime objects support lesser (equal)/greater (equal) comparisons.
You could instantiate a datetime object for the target time and fire the alarm as soon as the current time is greater-equal than the target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace:
        if rn == "18:00:00.000000":

With:
        if rn >= "18:00:00.000000":

Answer (score 8):

The technical problem here is that if you call `datetime.now()` over and over again, you can't always call it fast enough to get all of the possible values.  So `==` should instead be `>=`.  However, this still isn't very good.

A much better way to do this is to use `time.sleep()` instead of looping.

```
import datetime
import os
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

# Choose 6PM today as the time the alarm fires.
# This won't work well if it's after 6PM, though.
alarm_time = datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), datetime.time(18, 0, 0))

# Think of time.sleep() as having the operating system set an alarm for you,
# and waking you up when the alarm fires.
time.sleep((alarm_time - now).total_seconds())

os.system("start BTS_House_Of_Cards.mp3")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following to round to the next minute (or adapt for seconds etc)

```
import datetime as dt

rn  = dt.datetime.now()
# round to the next full minute
rn -= dt.timedelta( seconds = rn.second, microseconds =  rn.microsecond)
rn += dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

To adapt for seconds remove `seconds = rn.second` and then change `minutes` in the next line to `seconds`

**How it works**

Removes the seconds and microseconds from the current time and then adds on 1 minute therefore rounding it to the next whole minute.

Comment: Using the version adapted for seconds would most likely work better for an alarm actually.

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue for my IoT based project here is a simple tryout code written by me in python to invoke certain function at a given time here goes code

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
tempdatetimeobj = datetime.datetime.now()

try:
    while True:
        print("#################")

        now = str(datetime.datetime.now().time()) # convert a time in string

        print("Time is:- " + str(now))

        timestring = now[:5] 
     # Slice the time for eg time is 17:02:52:23656 it will 
     slice it to 17:02 only

    print("SLICE MAGIC :- "+ timestring)

    if timestring == '17:26' :  # after slicing operation only you can compare time  

       print('Triggered')

    elif timestring == '17:30' :

       print('again triggered')

    else :
       print('-_-')        

    sleep(60)




except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print('unHandled Exception Occured')
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using this technique? It's simple and works smoothly.

```
import datetime
import winsound  # exclusively for windows only,
# if you are on any other system you can use 'playsound' or 'simpleaudio' module.

alarm_hour = int(input("Set hour: "))
alarm_minutes = int(input("Set minutes: "))
am_pm = input("am or pm? ")

print(f"Waiting for time: {alarm_hour}:{alarm_minutes} {am_pm}")

# time conversion
# because datetime module returns time in military form i.e. 24 hrs format
if am_pm == 'pm':  # to convert pm to military time
    alarm_hour += 12

elif alarm_hour == 12 and am_pm == 'am':  # to convert 12am to military time
    alarm_hour -= 12

else:
    pass

while True:  # infinite loop starts to make the program running until time matches alarm time

    # ringing alarm + execution condition for alarm
    if alarm_hour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and alarm_minutes == datetime.datetime.now().minute:

        print("\nIt's the time!")
        winsound.Beep(1000, 1000)
        break
```

Obviously you can do more with the program by doing data validation for the inputs. Using the 'simpleaudio' module, you can add some interesting functions. And the number of other things you can do to increase the efficiency of the program.

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative that hasn't been mentioned which might work for you, depending on what your goals are: [signal.alarm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm).

`signal.alarm` is similar to the alarm(3) library call on Unix where setting a time will result in a SIGALRM signal being sent to a parent process in the future to denote when an asynchronous action should be taken (the default with an uncaught signal is a dead process).

Example:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 20 2019, 12:15:19)
[GCC 7.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> signal.alarm(1)
0
>>> Alarm clock
```

The key points when using signal.alarm(..) is the following:
 - The solution is best for a single process application; it should not be used if you need to have per-thread or multi-process timers.
 - You will need to setup a signal handler for `signal.SIGALRM`.

The key point when handling signals is:
 - Handle asynchronous

This approach is fairly basic and very OS-centric, but it's a simple, clean approach for doing things. There are other alternatives that could potentially be employed using the `kqueue`/`select` module (`poll`, etc, come to mind), other calls within the `signal` module, `concurrent.futures`/`multiprocessing` (there's a timeout option on some APIs).

Just one potential tool to use in your toolbox of timers.

A complete solution using `signal.alarm` can be found [here](https://github.com/ngie-eign/scratch/commit/87320901be777c4293c698aa90db2ce89d42b01b) (I adjusted the end time so I wouldn't have to wait forever for it to complete).

```
$ date; python3 play_house_of_cards.py ; date
Wed 10 Jul 2019 04:54:16 PM PDT
would have run `start BTS_House_Of_Cards.mp3`
Wed 10 Jul 2019 04:55:00 PM PDT
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using while loop with True like this:

loop = True
while loop:
rn = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())

```
if rn >= "18:00:00.00000":
    loop = False
```

Answer (score 0):

this alarm has almost every feature so it might be helpful for you if you want to make a perfect alarm

```
from pygame import mixer
from os import path
from sys import path as p
from time import sleep,strftime

try:
    while True: #it will give you another chance if you fill in letters or symbols
        hour=input('hour=')
        if hour.isdigit():# if input is digit 
            if len(hour)==1:#if the input has one digit
                hour2='0'+hour #it will add 0 in front of the input because time module gives 01 not 1 so it will convert 1(input) into 01 
            else:#if the input has two digit
                hour2=hour
        else:
            print('press any key to try again')

        min=input('Minute=')
        if min.isdigit():
            if len(min)==1:
                min2='0'+min 
            else:
                min2=min 

        ap=input('am/pm=')
        if ap=='am' or 'pm' or 'AM' or 'PM' or 'Am' or 'Pm' or 'aM' or 'pM':
            apm=ap.upper()
            break


    while True:
        x=strftime('%I')
        y=strftime('%M')
        z=strftime('%p')
        if x==hour2  and y==min2 and z==apm :
            print("Type 'h' for help")    
            
            while True:
                mixer.init()
```

you don't have to write the location of a file(c:\music\alone.mp3) just save the file in the same folder as the .py file

```
                music_=(path.join(p[0],'alone.mp3' ))
                mixer.music.load(music_) 
                mixer.music.play()
                
                stop=input('X=')
                if stop=='s' : #it will snooze the alarm for 5 min
                    time_=strftime('%I')
                    time2=strftime('%M')
                    time3=strftime('%S %p')
                    print('Alarm will sound at ',time_,':',int(time2)+5,':',time3)
                    mixer.music.stop()
                    sleep(300 )

                elif stop=='h':
                    print("1.Type 's' for snooze alarm / 2.Press any key except 's' and 'h' for turn off the alarm" )

                elif stop!='s' or 'h': #it will stop alarm
                    mixer.music.stop()
                    break
            break
except:
    print('Invalid Input: Please try again')
```

Comment: Looks nice! But you could add a few words about the specialtys of your approach and how it works and is different to the others.

Comment: It isn't a great idea to bump old questions to the active questions page. Especially when it is already answered.